# Tableviewcell shows nothing when trying to showing google ads

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, admob

I'm trying to show google ads (DFPBanner) on tableview cell. But it shows nothing.

I have set my cell identifier on the inspector same with the code.
[image: Identifier]

I put `func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView)` and I get a response that the ad is successfully received

Here is my code on `cellForRowAt`

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "middleAdsCell", for: indexPath) as! AdsCell

            adMiddle1View = AdsCell.cellMiddleView(rootVC: self, frame:cell.bounds) as! DFPBannerView
            for view in cell.contentView.subviews {
                if view.isKind(of: DFPBannerView.self) {
                    view.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
            adMiddle1View.delegate = self
            adMiddle1View.center = cell.center
            cell.addSubview(adMiddle1View)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.adMiddle1View.load(DFPRequest())
            }

            return cell
```

And here is my `AdsCell`

```
class func cellMiddleView(rootVC: UIViewController, frame: CGRect) -> GADBannerView {
        let middleView = DFPBannerView()
        middleView.frame = frame
        middleView.rootViewController = rootVC
        middleView.adUnitID = "/**80****/*****.COM_******_Apps_IOS/Zone_2"
        middleView.adSize = kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle
        //middleView.videoController.pause()
        return middleView
    }
```

The result is tableview just showing empty cell.
Please help me to resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: What is size of cell?

Comment: I think the line adMiddle1View.center = cell.center might be causing the problem. Comment that out and try it (you've already set the frame equal to cell.bounds anyway).

Comment: It is! Thanks man, didn't see it coming. @DavidSteppenbeckPhD

Comment: No problem - I guess it's because cell.center is the position of the cell in the cell's superview, rather than it's midpoint in it's own coordinate system... I'll add that as an official answer so everyone can see it easily, please mark as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line

```
adMiddle1View.center = cell.center
```

because the property `cell.center` is the center point of the cell in its superview, not the center point in it's own coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change return type of `cellMiddleView` method to `DFPBannerView` instead of `GADBannerView`.

Then after make sure size of `DFPBannerView` is same as listed here: [Banner Sizes](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/banner#banner_sizes)

Still, If you want to use custom size, then use `GADAdSizeFromCGSize` to add frame size for banner view.

```
let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 300, height: 50))
middleView.frame.size = adSize
```

If you have still issue with loading `DFPBannerView`, then conform delegate methods, and check what exactly issue and fix it.

```
/// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
}

/// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
            didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
    print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

/// Tells the delegate that a full-screen view will be presented in response
/// to the user clicking on an ad.
func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewWillPresentScreen")
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view will be dismissed.
func adViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewWillDismissScreen")
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view has been dismissed.
func adViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewDidDismissScreen")
}

/// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
/// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewWillLeaveApplication")
}
```

Comment: It fixed by commenting out the `adMiddle1View.center = cell.center` as @DavidSteppenbeckPhD says. Thanks though!